# ComboBox - select object from two properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I want my user to be able to select a Client (custom object) from a ComboBox in WPF. The ComboBox will show all clients by their FirstName (string) and LastName (string).

So basically my ViewModel exposes a single Client that is the selection the user will make, and a list of all Clients to use for populating the ComboBox. The ComboBox' declaration looks like:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Client}" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Text>
                    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} {1}">
                        <Binding Path="FirstName"/>
                        <Binding Path="LastName"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Of course that doesn't work because the Text property displays a raw client (showing the type name), and if the user types in a name it cannot be converted to a Client. This seems like a very simple thing to do yet by searching online I seem to find dozens of different solutions: create a wrapper type that has the properly formatted name, use a value converter, use data templating... I'm unfamiliar with all those WPF techniques, so please help me figure out the best (and hopefully simple!) solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is even a simpler way of doing this. Like you said, XAML binds to typename of the object and this comes from the ToString() method. This allows you to override the method and return the desired formatting without having complicated multiple bindings.

```
protected override ToString()
{
   return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName);
}
```

Might it also be that you are using the `Text` Property wrong and you need the SelectedItem?

Comment: Yes, but it won't help if you want to do anything more complex. For instance, first name in bold, last name in normal. For that, you need datatemplates

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson Aah that is true, haven't thought about that.

Comment: I still +1'd it. Simplicity is often overlooked ;)

Comment: This  worked perfectly for my needs and required next to no code at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you try something like this?

```
<!-- Example assumes DataContext of ComboBox is MasterViewModel below -->
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text={Binding FirstName} Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
                <TextBlock Text={Binding LastName}/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Then bind directly to the viewmodel properties

```
public class ClientViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event EventHandler<PropertyChangedEventArgs> PropertyChanged; 

    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return this.firstName; }
        set 
        {
            this.firstName = value; // Dont forget to raise PropertyChanged!
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return this.firstName; }
        set 
        {
            this.lastName = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Exposing an `IEnumerable<ClientViewModel>` in your MasterViewModel like this

```
public class MasterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private IEnumerable<ClientViewModel> _clients = new ClientViewModel[] 
    {
        new ClientViewModel() { FirstName = "Dave", LastName = "Cameron" }, 
        new ClientViewModel() { FirstName = "Ed", LastName = "Miliband" }, 
    }
    public IEnumerable<ClientViewModel> Clients
    {
        get { return _clients; } 
    } 
}
```

The power of DataTemplates means you can present your data in whichever way you like. Using a StackPanel or Grid in the DataTemplate and multiple textboxes is the best way to go here.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest way is to just add a custom property to the `Client` object.  So client ends up being like this.  Note that the `Client` object MUST implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in one regard or another in order for the binding infrastructure to pick up on changes.

```
public class Client : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   //other fields/properies
   private string firstName;
   private string lastName;

   public string FirstName
   {
      get { return this.firstName; }
      set 
      {
         this.firstName = value;
         this.FirePropertyChanged("FirstName");
         this.FirePropertyChanged("DisplayName");
      }
   }

   public string LastName
   {
      get { return this.firstName; }
      set 
      {
         this.lastName = value;
         this.FirePropertyChanged("LastName");
         this.FirePropertyChanged("DisplayName");
      }
   }

   public string DisplayName
   {
      get 
      {
          return string.Format("{0} {1}", this.firstName, this.lastName);
      }
   }

   protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
   {
      if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
         this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
   }
}
```

Then you just have a very simple `ComboBox` declaration pointing at the new `DisplayName` property:

**EDIT:**

Instead of using the `Text` property, use the `SelectedItem` property with Two-way binding to match it up to your ViewModel.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding Client, Mode=TwoWay" ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" />
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with this is that when I select a client from the list, I get: "System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. (...) Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type '[MyAppNamespace].Client'."

Comment: Ah, I see what the problem is...assuming the "Client" property is of type "Client", see my edit...

Comment: I +1'd this for the FirePropertyChanged, which I omitted from my answer for brevity

Answer (score 1):

This should work out of the box, but you don't seem to be binding the selected item of the combo.

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" IsEditable="True"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Client}" >
```

I'm not clear on why you've got the combo editable though. Are you saying the user can type a firstname / lastname to select? In that case you need converter.